# Bildung des Perfekts mit manchen Verben

Tags: perfect-tense

I have some questions when to use "haben" and "sein" when building the temporal form "Das Perfekt" with the following verbs:

- Begegnen
- Heiraten
- Abbrennen

I'm trying to find out why the following sentences are incorrect:

1. **Ich bin im Januar geheiratet.** (It should be "Ich habe [...] **geheiratet**", but why? "Heiraten" is supposed to indicate a "Zustandswechsel", isn't it?)
2. **Wo habt ihr euch zum ersten Mal begegnet?** (It should be "Wo **seid** ihr [...] begegnet", so does "begegnen" indicate a "Ortswechsel" or "Zustandswechsel"?)
3. **Das Haus hat bis auf die Grundmauern abgebrannt**. (This one got me a little confused. It should be "Das Haus ist [...] **abgebrannt**." I understand that there is a "Zustandswechsel"; the house burned down. Ok, but there is an "Akkusativergänzung" --> "auf die Grundmauern", so why do we use "sein" instead of "haben"?)

Comment: The second correction isn't correct either. Instead of *Wo sei**t** ...* it should be *Wo sei**d** ...*

Comment: (for the small side thing: https://www.seid-seit.de/)

Comment: Note the "Zustandswechsel" vs. "Ortswechsel" rule is just a general rule, there's more to it (and a bunch of exceptions).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to already know that taking an accusative object tends to go along with having a "haben" perfect. So the first two are not a surprise, because it is "jemande**n** heiraten" but "jemande**m** begegnen". The "auf die Grundmauern" part in the third example is not relevant for this, though, because it is "**bis** auf die Grundmauern", so you shouldn't count this as either accusative or dative, but as using a preposition (which happens to take accusative). Contrast this with

> Ich habe die Grundmauern abgebrannt.

Note that these rules do not always work, for example we have

> Ich bin einen Marathon gelaufen.

The verb "laufen" has a perfect with "sein", even though there is an accusative object in this case. (Or maybe "hat" would actually be correct here, too, but "bin" certainly is.)

Comment: It could also very well be "Ich habe einen Marathon gelaufen"

Comment: As an Austrian I would strongly object – „haben gelaufen“ is a purely German thing (and then probably not in all parts of Germany, but what do I know.) Isn't it fun to have a pluricentric language? :-)

Comment: @tofro, actually, I have long wondered about this, and even considered asking about it in the past. I think my Sprachgefühl used to tell me “habe” here, but it doesn’t anymore. Of course, I can be totally wrong.

Comment: That's a special case: "Ich habe einen Marathon gelaufen" is not so much about the movement, but rather about the *completion of the task*. That's why "haben" is fine here, also because it's a transitive usage.

Comment: @tofro, I absolutely understand the difference, I just don't hear people say it. I can find some instances on the Web, but as we know from some questions here, that doesn't mean that it's correct. Well, perhaps I should ask that question after all.

Comment: @tofro I'm from Hesse, and to me *Ich habe einen Marathon gelaufen* sounds plain **wrong**.